# Next server actions

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, react-query, server-action

I'm currently using Next.js **server actions** in my project with **React Query**, and I'm facing an issue. I've defined separate custom hooks for mutations and used server actions there. The problem arises when the server throws an error in my custom hook; React Query is unable to track it in the onError method.

I've resorted to using another package (**next-safe-action**) for mutations to complete the project quickly. However, I'm still curious about how I can solve this problem using React Query only. Do you have any suggestions or solutions?

**Next Safe Actions code:**

```
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import { InferType } from 'yup';
import { Button, Input, Textarea } from '@nextui-org/react';
import { useAction } from 'next-safe-action/hooks';
import { contactSupportTeam } from '@/server/actions';
import { InputError } from '../ui/InputError';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';
import { contactFormValidationSchema } from '@/validation';

export type ContactFormType = InferType<
  typeof contactFormValidationSchema
>;
export default function ContactForm() {
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(contactFormValidationSchema),
  });
  const { execute, status } = useAction(contactSupportTeam, {
    onSuccess: data => {
      if (data.error) {
        toast.error(data.error);
      }
      if (data.success) {
        toast.success(data.success);
      }
    },
    onError: data => {
      toast.error(data.serverError as string);
    },
  });
  const onSubmit = (formData: ContactFormType) => {
    execute(formData);
  };
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      className='bg-[#EBEADC] py-8 rounded-xl lg:w-[85%] w-full mx-auto lg:px-8 px-4'
    >
      <div className='border-b-1 py-3 border-b-gray-300'>
        <p className='text-gray-700 text-xl'>Write us a message</p>
      </div>
      <div className='lg:py-2 py-2  w-full '>
        <Controller
          name='name'
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <>
              <span className='text-gray-600  text-[12px]  font-medium'>
                Name:
              </span>
              <Input
                labelPlacement='outside'
                {...field}
              />
            </>
          )}
        />
        <InputError inputName='name' errors={errors} />
      </div>
      <div className='lg:py-2 py-1  w-full '>
        <Controller
          name='email'
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <>
              <span className='text-gray-600  text-[12px]  font-medium'>
                Email:
              </span>
              <Input
                labelPlacement='outside'
                {...field}
              />
            </>
          )}
        />
        <InputError inputName='email' errors={errors} />
      </div>
      <div className='lg:py-2 py-1  w-full '>
        <Controller
          name='topic'
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <>
              <span className='text-gray-600  text-[12px]  font-medium'>
                Topic:
              </span>
              <Input
                labelPlacement='outside'
                {...field}
              />
            </>
          )}
        />
        <InputError inputName='topic' errors={errors} />
      </div>
      <div className='lg:py-2 py-1  w-full '>
        <Controller
          name='message'
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <>
              <span className='text-gray-600  text-[12px]  font-medium'>
                Message:
              </span>
              <Textarea
                minRows={7}
                labelPlacement='outside'
                {...field}
              />
            </>
          )}
        />
        <InputError inputName='message' errors={errors} />
      </div>
      <div className='text-end sm:mt-5 mt-3'>
        <Button
          type='submit'
          radius='full'
          isLoading={status === 'executing'}
          className='bg-primary-300 text-white'
        >
          Send
        </Button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Server Actions code:

```
export const contactSupportTeam = action(
  contactFormValidationSchema,
  async body => {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE}/contacts`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        ...APPLICATION_JSON_HEADER,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      const error: NServerErrorType = await response.json();

      return { error: error.message || 'Something went wrong' };
    }
    const data: { data: string } = await response.json();

    return { success: data.data };
  }
);
```

**Validation Schema**

```
export const contactFormValidationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required('This field is required'),
  email: yup
    .string()
    .required('This field is required')
    .email('Please enter a valid email'),
  topic: yup.string().required('This field is required'),
  message: yup.string().required('This field is required'),
});
```